# Ignoring specific characters in read table of list

Tags: r, read.table

I have the following list:

```
> str1<-'cor [1] 0.8832846 0.8880517 0.8881286 0.8845148 0.8832846 0.8880517 0.8818238 0.8767492 0.8876672 0.8822851 0.8854375 0.8850531 0.8835153
[14] 0.8832846 0.8908965 0.8803629'
I use the following command:
> df1 <- read.table(text=scan(text=str1, what='', quiet=TRUE), header=TRUE)
```

However, `[1]` and `[14]` are included in df1. What can I change in `df1` in order to ignore all `[x]` (where x is a number?

Comment: Do you want `cor` included?

Comment: Yes. cor is the headline (name) of the table column.

Comment: 16 rows without the 'cor'. Each number is a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the square brackets including the numbers inside with `gsub`, `scan` and then `read.table` as in the OP's post.

```
read.table(text=scan(text=gsub('\\[\\d+\\]', '', str1),
                             what='', quiet=TRUE), header=TRUE)
#      cor
#1  0.8832846
#2  0.8880517
#3  0.8881286
#4  0.8845148
#5  0.8832846
#6  0.8880517
#7  0.8818238
#8  0.8767492
#9  0.8876672
#10 0.8822851
#11 0.8854375
#12 0.8850531
#13 0.8835153
#14 0.8832846
#15 0.8908965
#16 0.8803629
```

Or without using `scan` as @Richard Scriven mentioned

```
read.table(text=gsub('\\s+(\\[\\d+\\]\\s+)?', '\n', str1), header=TRUE)
```

Comment: You could do without `scan()` by replacing the spaces with line-breaks `read.table(text = gsub("(\\[\\d+\\])|\\s", "\n", str1), header = TRUE)`

Comment: @RichardScriven  Thanks, I was trying a similar approach when you commented.